# Safely wrap long HTML lines to avoid Postfix's smtp_line_length_limit

Tags: php, html, word-wrap, postfix-mta, tidy

In order to avoid Postfix from wrapping ultra long lines after `smtp_line_length_limit` (usually 998 characters) I am currently using [php's tidy library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php) to wrap long lines in HTML emails (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498883/html-safe-wrapping-of-long-lines)):

```
$oTidy = new tidy();
$message = $oTidy->repairString($message,
    array("show-errors" => 0, "show-warnings" => false, "force-output" => true, 
    "alt-text" => "Please display images", "bare" => true, "doctype" => "auto", 
    "drop-empty-paras" => false, "fix-bad-comments" => false, "fix-uri" => true, 
    "join-styles" => false, "merge-divs" => true, "merge-spans" => true, 
    "preserve-entities" => true, "wrap" => 68),
    "utf8"
);
```

Tidy is really good in wrapping long lines with respect to leaving HTML and CSS valid.
Unfortunately it does a lot more like trying to fix invalid HTML markup, changing HTML tags, doctypes, etc.

I only need the line wrapping however - the other stuff tidy does is overhead and sometimes rather annoying than anything else.

Now I have tried to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)'s `wrapText()` function. Unfortunately I have found a [bug](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/89) that makes it useless for me.
PHPMailer converts this source code

```
<html>
    <body>
        Loremipsumdolorsitametconsetetursadipscing<span style="font-family:'Courier New',sans-serif">lorem</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

to

```
<html>
    <body>
        Loremipsumdolorsitametconsete<span style="font-family:'Courier
        New',sans-serif">lorem</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

breaking the font formatting (Courier New) for the word lorem in some clients.

Now my questions:

**How can I wrap HTML lines safely without damaging HTML and CSS?**

**How does Tidy do it? Should I use a DOM parser? Is there a php version of the Tidy source code (I haven't found one)?**

Comment: wordwrap()? as long as you don't allow word breaks, then the html/css should come through just fine. unless, of course, you have some ridiculously long css class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to go seems to be `quoted-printable` encoding as it can break lines into small chunks of characters while preserving readability for content filters without the risk of destroying any formatting.

`Base64` would also be an option but would raise the risk of spam classification.

Both options increase the length of the source code however (`quoted-printable` especially for non-ascii characters).

Side note:
PHPMailer's `wrapText()` [will not be fixed](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/89#) as the described problems can be solved through the mail encoding as described above.

Answer (score 3):

1. encode your text into base64 using `base64_encode()`
2. set appropriate MIME header
3. split this base64-ed blob into 76 character wide chunks using `chunk_split()`
4. Profit!

Comment: How much longer will my source code be after encoding it in base64?

Comment: 3. split this base64-ed blob into 80 caracter wide chinks

Comment: Sizewise I mean. It will be base64 encoded so the total size of the file will be bigger, right? I understand that each line will only be 80 characters long.

Comment: Right. Though, as this problem doesn't bother not a single email service or client software (as every one of them do encode their emails in base64), I see no reason for this question at all

Comment: Base64 encoding is not used all the time. Mainly because of Spam reasons. The receiving MTA cannot content filter right away. `quoted-printable` might be a solution though. I'll look into it.

Comment: Errr.... spam? Do you really believe that "The receiving MTA cannot content filter [spam] right away"? Anyway, you can use quoted printable as well