# String too long | using chunk_split

Tags: php

I have a `heredoc` var. in php and sending it via `POST` to an `mail.php` - everything worked fine, but since `web.de` and `gmx.net` are such tools they won´t accept my mails "`String too Long 500...`" - using chunk_split solved the problem:

```
$text1 = chunk_split($text1, 1212,"\r\n");
```

But now the layout is screwed up sometimes. So instead of `Hello there...`
It makes an empty space `Hello t here...`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of content.

If your content is HTML, one way to handle it is to [run the content through tidy::repairString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5500589/931925).

If your content is text (without a structure and formatting language), breaking long lines during mail transfer is one of the things [quoted-printable encoding](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php) does. Run your content through that. Send your message with a header named `Content-Transfer-Encoding` with value `QUOTED-PRINTABLE`. Mail clients will automatically put the content back together before displaying it.

Comment: Well kinda works, there is no exception any more, but the layout is totally screwed up... No pictures, no fonts, nothing

Comment: ok, modified to distinguish two cases: text content and html content.